# Entropy change in each step of Carnot Cycle

Tags: entropy, carnot-cycle

How to go about calculating the entropy change in each step of a Carnot Cycle given only $T_{h}$, $T_{l}$, and the work performed per cycle?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle  Scroll down to the temperature-entropy diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Carnot cycle is reversible, any entropy change is the result of heat transfer between the heat engine and the surroundings. Since there is no heat transfer during the reversible adiabatic processes, the entropy changes occur only during the reversible isothermal (constant temperature) expansion and compression processes. Those entropy changes are

$$\Delta S_{exp}=\frac{Q_{H}}{T_H}\tag{1}$$

$$\Delta S_{comp}=\frac{Q_{L}}{T_L}\tag{2}$$

Where $Q_H$ is the heat added by the high temperature reservoir and $Q_L$ is the heat rejected to the low temperature reservoir. Note that $Q_L$ is negative because it is heat out, and $Q_H$ is positive because it is heat added.

Since the total entropy change for a cycle is zero,

$$\Delta S_{comp}=-\Delta S_{exp}\tag{3}$$

So if you can determine either $Q_H$ or $Q_L$ from the information given, you can determine both entropy changes. To determine $Q_H$ from the information given, proceed as follows:

The Carnot cycle efficiency is given by

$$\eta=1-\frac{T_L}{T_H}=\frac{T_{H}-T_{L}}{T_H}\tag{4}$$

The efficiency of any heat engine cycle, including the Carnot cycle, is the net work done divided by the gross heat added, or

$$\eta=\frac{W}{Q_H}\tag{5}$$

Equating the right sides of equations (4) and (5) and solving for $Q_H$

$$Q_{H}=\frac{(W)(T_H)}{T_{H}-T_{L}}\tag{6}$$

The change in entropy during the isothermal expansion is then

$$\Delta S_{exp}=\frac{Q_H}{T_H}=\frac{W}{T_{H}-T_L}\tag{7}$$

Then, since $\Delta S_{comp}=-\Delta S_{exp}$

$$\Delta S_{comp}=\frac{-W}{T_{H}-T_L}\tag{7}$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The entropy change is $$\Delta S = \frac{Q}{T}$$.

There is no heat $Q$ in the adiabatic steps.

The efficiency of a Carnot cycle

$$\eta = \frac{W}{Q_H} = 1- \frac{Q_C}{Q_H} = 1- \frac{T_C}{T_H}$$

Which should give the necessary quantities for the isothermal steps

Comment: isotropic should be isothermal.

Comment: Of course, thanks.